# Connect to backend of VSO

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to get the server info of my VSO account and access using SQL Server?

I've tried logging in using the URL

```
         {account}.visualstudio.com
```

But I got a sever not found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the back-end databases are SQL Azure instances, different from the TFS on-premise databases. I cannot see MS ever giving you access to the database - maybe the data, but not the database.

You can only use the API (old and new REST) and Power BI tools to perform queries.

If you have a specific problem you are trying to solve, post it as a new question because it may be possible without database access.

Comment: Can I get access to the SQL Azure instance? I know you can connect to cloud servers via SQL Server.

Comment: No, they are hosted by Microsoft in their Azure instances. If you really need access to something, I suggest you contact Microsoft Support.